# gcp redis with authorized_network on a shared subnetwork

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, terraform, vpc

I want to create a GCP redis instance on a service project that have a shared subnetwork from a host project shared with it. I don't want the redis instance to be on the top level of the vpc-network. But be part of a subnetwork on the vpc-network.

So instead of authorized_network equal to:
`"projects/infra/global/networks/infra"`.
I want the authorized_network to be equal to:
`"projects/infra/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/service"`

Under the vpc-network->Shared-VPC tab I can see my subnetwork "service" shared with the service-project and I can see it belongs to the "infra" vpc-network. But when I try to create the instance in the gui or with terraform I can't select the subnetwork only the vpc-network top level "infra".

terraform code I tried but did't work:

```
resource "google_redis_instance" "test" {
  auth_enabled       = true
  authorized_network = "projects/infra/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/service"
  connect_mode       = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_ACCESS"
  name               = "test"
  project            = local.infra_project_id
  display_name       = "test"
  memory_size_gb     = 1
  redis_version      = "REDIS_6_X"
  region             = "europe-west1"
}
```

terraform code that works, but on vpc-network not on subnetwork:

```
resource "google_redis_instance" "test" {
  auth_enabled       = true
  authorized_network = "projects/infra/global/networks/infra"
  connect_mode       = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_ACCESS"
  name               = "test"
  project            = local.infra_project_id
  display_name       = "test"
  memory_size_gb     = 1
  redis_version      = "REDIS_6_X"
  region             = "europe-west1"
}
```

First of is this possible?

Second what is needed to get it to work?

Comment: If you can see the Subnetwork but you cannot access it when you create your instance, it means that you do not have the appropriate roles to complete the task. Shared VPC makes use of Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for delegated administration. Using Shared VPC networks involves a minimum of three different administrative Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles. For more details about each role and information about optional ones, see the administrators and IAM section of the Shared VPC overview. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#iam_in_shared_vpc

Comment: Hi, @IsmaelClementeAguirre I don't know if I am missing any admin roles I added a bunch from the once i already had but did not change the options available to me when creating the redis instance network.
Billing Account Administrator,
Compute OS Admin Login,
Folder Admin,
Identity Platform Admin,
Logging Admin,
Organization Policy Administrator,
Owner,
Support Account Administrator, 
Compute Shared VPC Admin,
Connector Admin,
Organization Administrator,
Serverless VPC Access Admin,
Service Networking Admin

Comment: Please review that you have the role: Service Project Admin assigned to your account in the projects related to the subnet. A Shared VPC Admin defines a Service Project Admin by granting an IAM principal the Network User (compute.networkUser) role to either the whole host project or select subnets of its Shared VPC networks. And if you already have the role assigned, please review that you have Project-Level permissions.

Comment: Hi, I have all the role assigned to me are on organization level and form my understanding it should be propagated down to all projects. But after som more investigation I also found that I can create a VM instance on wanted subnet in the service project. But for redis or Postgres this is still not available. So I am starting to thing the network is done correctly just that redis and Postgres aren't allowed to be placed on subnets.

Comment: You can try configure connectMode value using DIRECT_PEERING. When using the direct peering mode, Memorystore creates a VPC peering between the customer VPC network and the VPC network in the Google managed project. The peering is created automatically during instance creation and requires no additional steps from the user. In this link you can find a complete “how to”. https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances#creating_a_redis_instance_that_uses_a_centralized_ip_address_range

Comment: And if this solution is not working for you, here's a complete overview about networking for memorystore for redis.
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/networking